# dotnet.exe CLI - Check if a newer nuget version is available

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, nuget, dotnet-cli

I developed a (non-public) nuget-tool. The installation was very easy:

```sh
dotnet tool install dotnet-mytoolname -g
```

My colleagues will also install these tool by the command.

In future I will release new versions of `dotnet-mytoolname`. Consumers will update it easy with dotnet.exe.

Now my problem:
If a developer runs an outdated version of that tool then I will hint it in console output (something like "a newer version is available").
How I can check with dotnet.exe if a new version is available?

The command below would do it but only for nuget.org. But our nuget-tool is not hosted on nuget.org but on a private azure-devops server.

```sh
dotnet tools search dotnet-mytoolname
```

The nuget-tool `dotnet-mytoolname` is a C# console-project.

Have you any ideas how I can check within that project if a newer version is available on azure-devops?

Comment: You could try using https://github.com/dotnet-outdated/dotnet-outdated

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [DavidG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1663001/davidg). Posting your suggestions as an answer to help other community members.

Installing dotnet outdated application will help you in resolving your issue
install [.Net core](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) and run the following command

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-outdated-tool
```

Here is how it will use

```
Usage: dotnet outdated [options] <Path>

Arguments:
  Path                                       The path to a .sln, .csproj or .fsproj file, or to a directory containing a .NET Core solution/project. If none is specified, the current directory will be used.

Options:
  --version                                  Show version information
  -?|-h|--help                               Show help information
  -i|--include-auto-references               Specifies whether to include auto-referenced packages.
  -pre|--pre-release <PRERELEASE>            Specifies whether to look for pre-release versions of packages. Possible values: Auto (default), Always or Never.
  -vl|--version-lock <VERSION_LOCK>          Specifies whether the package should be locked to the current Major or Minor version. Possible values: None (default), Major or Minor.
  -t|--transitive                            Specifies whether it should detect transitive dependencies.
  -td|--transitive-depth <TRANSITIVE_DEPTH>  Defines how many levels deep transitive dependencies should be analyzed. Integer value (default = 1)
  -u|--upgrade[:<TYPE>]                      Specifies whether outdated packages should be upgraded. Possible values for <TYPE> is Auto (default) or Prompt.
  -f|--fail-on-updates                       Specifies whether it should return a non-zero exit code when updates are found.
  -inc|--include <FILTER_INCLUDE>            Specifies to only look at packages where the name contains the provided string. Culture and case insensitive. If provided multiple times, a single match is enough to include a package.
  -exc|--exclude <FILTER_EXCLUDE>            Specifies to only look at packages where the name does not contain the provided string. Culture and case insensitive. If provided multiple times, a single match is enough to exclude a package.
  -o|--output <OUTPUT_FILENAME>              Specifies the filename for a generated report. (Use the -of|--output-format option to specify the format. JSON by default.)
  -of|--output-format <OUTPUT_FILE_FORMAT>   Specifies the output format for the generated report. Possible values: json (default) or csv.
  -ot|--older-than <NUMBER_OF_DAYS>          Only include package versions that are older than the specified number of days.
```

Check this [link](https://github.com/dotnet-outdated/dotnet-outdated) which will give you complete information about dotnet outdated packages.

Comment: Thank you for the summary but that tool will currently not help because it only can check local tools but not global installed ones (see https://github.com/dotnet-outdated/dotnet-outdated/issues/32).